Undefined array key 0 in wp-includes/plugin.php on line 1004
Hi I have an issiue with this error "Undefined array key 0 in wp-includes/plugin.php on line 1004" I have no clue how to fix it or what it is casued by. Does anyone have any idea what it can be caused by or ho to fix it because i didn't find any information about this error any help would be appreciated.
I have no clue how to fix it or what it is casued by.

It sounds like you might be on the wrong site to ask for help. This is a site for programming Q&A; while this problem might conceivably be fixed by programming that doesn't make it about programming. Try [webmasters.se] but step 1 would be disabling all plugins and themes, and re-enabling one by one. If that doesn't help, step 2 would be reinstall of WP

It was custom plugin that I had that was making this error.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I see that a lot when the variable being logic checked is not an array.  You might add logic to check is_array().
if (is_array( $callback )) {
    if ( is_object( $callback[0] ) ) {
        // Object class calling.
        return spl_object_hash( $callback[0] ) . $callback[1];
    } elseif ( is_string( $callback[0] ) ) {
        // Static calling.
        return $callback[0] . '::' . $callback[1];
    }
}


But I don't know what is causing that and i have this error every 5 seconds or something like that. And I think it's not good to modify wp file plugin.php.

First you can check if the array is not null or isset
isset($array[$key])

Or you can try by keeping the code in a try catch block

But I don't know what is causing that and i have this error every 5 seconds or something like that. And I think it's not good to modify wp file plugin.php.

plugin.php file contains the functions and hooks. If possible you can share the code snippet here or even try to update the wordpress, plugins and php version on the server.

you can check though conditional statements that if the key exists before attempting to access it
if (isset($array[0])) {     }

else {
    }

in plugin.php on line 1004

This would mean changing base code - I would have thought it was more a case of why this line fails rather than just changing it.

sometime it happens due to updation of theme or plugins or due to dependencies of one to another

I have the error like every 5 seconds but i don't know why. But I think it's not good to modify plugin.php because it's default wp file. And after wp update it will be replaced.

you need to add this is child theme
